# Getting error Property 'searchArray' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'

Tags: reactjs, api

i am working on react Autocomplete text field when i use this with api then its working fine but when i start using API then getting error  **Property 'searchArray' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'**. i am using react with react material-Ui. Here i am getting error **"{this.state.searchArray.map((row: any) =>"**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Autocomplete from "./Autocomplete";
import ApiService from "../../service/ApiService";
const style = {
    flexGrow: 1
}
export class SearchScripComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props: any){
    super(props);
    this.state ={
        searchArray:[],
        message: null
    }
    this.searchScripData = this.searchScripData.bind(this); 
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.searchScripData(this.requesDATAScrip());
}

requesDATAScrip()
{
let data1= { "isActive": true };
return data1;
}

  searchScripData(searchScrip: any) {
    ApiService.searchScripDataList(searchScrip)
        .then((res) => {
           this.setState({searchArray: res.data.data} )
        });
}
  render() {
    return (

<div>
      <h1>React Autocomplete Demo</h1>
      <h2>Start typing and experience the autocomplete wizardry!</h2>
      <div>
      {this.state.searchArray.map((row: any) => (
      <div>{row.category}</div>
      ))}
      </div>
      <Autocomplete
        suggestions={[
          "Alligator",
          "Bask",
          "Crocodilian",
          "Death Roll",
          "Eggs",
          "Jaws",
          "Reptile",
          "Solitary",
          "Tail",
          "Wetlands"
        ]}
      />
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchScripComponent;
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample project on GitHub or through https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: `.then((res) => {this.setState({searchArray: res.data.data} )})` might have returned a non-array data. Check it with console.log

Comment: i have data in array

Comment: @mjabadilla thank you this query solved. can u help me for one more query. i want print array here **<Autocomplete  suggestions={here i want} />**